# get month range using new Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function firstDayOfMonth(given_month) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setMonth(given_month, 1);
            return d.toISOString();
        }

        function lastDayOfMonth(given_month) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setMonth(given_month + 1, 0);
            return d.toISOString();
        }

        var temp = {
            firstDayOfMonth: firstDayOfMonth(given_month),
            lastDayOfMonth: lastDayOfMonth(given_month)
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))
```

Trying to get first day of the month and last day of the month to develop a monthly report. I got `{"firstDayOfMonth":"2016-11-01T09:45:30.998Z","lastDayOfMonth":"2016-11-30T09:45:30.998Z"}`
 for temp, is that normal? why it's 9:45 something?

Comment: That will be current time. You need to set hours to 0, minutes to 0 the same way you have set it for month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the right thing. You just need to set hour for start and end day:

```
firstDayOfMonth.setHours(0,0,0,0);
lastDayOfMonth.setHours(23,59,59,999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just normalize date object with H/M/S set to 12:00:00, like this:

```
const givenMonth = 6;

const normalizeTime = d => {
    d.setHours(12);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    return d;
};

const getISODate = (month, day) => {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(month, day);
    return normalizeTime(d).toISOString();
};

const temp = {
    firstDayOfMonth: getISODate(givenMonth, 1),
    lastDayOfMonth: getISODate(givenMonth + 1, 0)
};

temp;
```

Comment: Isn't using *the middle of the day* a little dangerous if they use the "month" for range checking values?